# Double click zoom not correctly scrolling to clicked part of image in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

Details:
I am working on implementing an image viewer modal in React that includes a double-click zoom functionality. The goal is to zoom in on the image when double-clicked, and also scroll to the clicked part of the image to keep it visible after the zoom.

I have implemented the double-click zoom functionality, but I am facing issues with scrolling to the clicked part of the image after zooming. The scroll position seems incorrect, and the image parent does not scroll correctly.

Code:
I'm using a combination of React state and event handling to achieve this functionality. Below is the code snippet for the component:

```
import clsx from 'clsx'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import classes from './styles.module.scss'
import { IImageViewerProps } from '.'

const DOUBLE_CLICK_ZOOM_RATE = 0.5
const ZOOM_RATE = 0.1
const DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX = 2

export function ImageViewer({ src, title }: IImageViewerProps) {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const ref = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null)
  const [imgScale, setImgScale] = useState(1)
  const [doubleClickCount, setDoubleClickCount] = useState(0)
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false)
  const [dragStart, setDragStart] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 })

  const handleDoubleClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()

    if (doubleClickCount < DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX) {
      const newScale = imgScale + DOUBLE_CLICK_ZOOM_RATE

      // After zooming, calculate the new scroll position to keep the clicked part visible
      if (containerRef.current && ref.current) {
        const containerRect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
        const imageRect = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()
        const x = (e.clientX - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width
        const y = (e.clientY - containerRect.top) / containerRect.height

        const newScrollLeft =
          x * (imageRect.width * newScale - containerRect.width)
        const newScrollTop =
          y * (imageRect.height * newScale - containerRect.height)

        console.log(newScrollLeft)
        containerRef.current.scrollLeft = 10
        containerRef.current.scrollTop = newScrollTop

        setImgScale(newScale)
        setDoubleClickCount((prevState) => prevState + 1)
      }
    } else {
      setImgScale(1)
      setDoubleClickCount(0)
    }
  }

  const handleMouseDown = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()

    setIsDragging(true)
    setDragStart({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY })
  }

  const handleMouseMove = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()

    if (isDragging && containerRef.current) {
      const deltaX = e.clientX - dragStart.x
      const deltaY = e.clientY - dragStart.y

      containerRef.current.scrollLeft -= deltaX
      containerRef.current.scrollTop -= deltaY

      setDragStart({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY })
    }
  }

  const handleMouseUp = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()

    setIsDragging(false)
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.imgContainer)}
      ref={containerRef}
       onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
    >
      <img
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          width: `${imgScale * 100}%`
        }}
        src={src}
        alt={title}
        className={clsx(classes.imgContainer__image)}
        onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
.imgContainer{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow: scroll;

  &__image{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 30vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Issue:
The problem is that the image parent does not scroll correctly to the clicked part of the image after double-click zooming. The calculated newScrollLeft and newScrollTop values don't seem to be working as expected.

Question:
What changes can be made to the handleDoubleClick function to ensure that the image parent scrolls correctly to the clicked part of the image after the double-click zoom?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting the container's `scrollLeft` to an arbitrary value of `10`:

```js
containerRef.current.scrollLeft = 10
```

Consider using the `newScrollLeft` calculated value instead:

```js
containerRef.current.scrollLeft = newScrollLeft
```

Furthermore, you'd want to set the `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` values of the container *after* the `<img>` has increased in width. This is because the container needs to be scrollable for any scrolling to occur:

```js
setImgScale(newScale);
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  containerRef.current.scrollLeft = newScrollLeft;
  containerRef.current.scrollTop = newScrollTop;
});
```

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;
const classes = {
  imgContainer: "imgContainer",
  imgContainer__image: "imgContainer__image",
};

const DOUBLE_CLICK_ZOOM_RATE = 0.5;
const ZOOM_RATE = 0.1;
const DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX = 2;

function ImageViewer({ src, title }) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [imgScale, setImgScale] = useState(1);
  const [doubleClickCount, setDoubleClickCount] = useState(0);
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [dragStart, setDragStart] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });

  const handleDoubleClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (doubleClickCount < DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX) {
      const newScale = imgScale + DOUBLE_CLICK_ZOOM_RATE;

      // After zooming, calculate the new scroll position to keep the clicked part visible
      if (containerRef.current && ref.current) {
        const containerRect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const imageRect = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = (e.clientX - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width;
        const y = (e.clientY - containerRect.top) / containerRect.height;

        const newScrollLeft =
          x * (imageRect.width * newScale - containerRect.width);
        const newScrollTop =
          y * (imageRect.height * newScale - containerRect.height);

        setImgScale(newScale);
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          containerRef.current.scrollLeft = newScrollLeft;
          containerRef.current.scrollTop = newScrollTop;
        });

        setDoubleClickCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      }
    } else {
      setImgScale(1);
      setDoubleClickCount(0);
    }
  };

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsDragging(true);
    setDragStart({
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY,
    });
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (isDragging && containerRef.current) {
      const deltaX = e.clientX - dragStart.x;
      const deltaY = e.clientY - dragStart.y;

      containerRef.current.scrollLeft -= deltaX;
      containerRef.current.scrollTop -= deltaY;

      setDragStart({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
      });
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.imgContainer)}
      ref={containerRef}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
    >
      <img
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          width: `${imgScale * 100}%`,
        }}
        src={src}
        alt={title}
        className={clsx(classes.imgContainer__image)}
        onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      />{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(
  <ImageViewer src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" title="Foo" />
);
```

```css
.imgContainer {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.imgContainer__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 30vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clsx@2.0.0/dist/clsx.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCu3d6+wkHB+8Rkb9HdCVvg5Ua7WBkZ6+iaLG5he9qY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble setting the 'scrollLeft' property, it just doesn't seem to work in the browser, it always 0

Comment: Consider reviewing the answer I gave above. This `scrollLeft` property is not always `0` in the above solution.